# Build 3D Object by define a function

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

I have function z[i][j]=func(x[i],y[j]), where x and y are changing from -1 to 1 with step 0.1.

Need to build 3D object with z=sin(x+y), when x<0 and z=cos(x+y) when x>0

I made few variations (1 is working right (i guess)), but need to define a function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
x=np.linspace(-1,1,21)
y=np.linspace(-1,1,21)
x1,y1= np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = []
for i in x: 
    zz = [] 
    for j in y: 
        if i<0:
           zz.append(np.sin(i+j))
        else:
           zz.append(np.cos(i+j))
    z.append(zz)
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5,6))
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(x,y,z,10,cmap='inferno')
plt.show
```

UPD: I must import code (function) bellow in my working code, but dunno how to make it work with 3D plot)

```
import numpy as np
def func(x,y):
  if (x<0):
    return [np.sin(x+y)]
  elif (x>0):
    return [np.cos(x+y)]
  else:
    return [0]
print(func(1,4))
```

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(-1,1,21)
y=np.linspace(-1,1,21)
def fun(i,j): 
  for i in x: 
      fun = [] 
      for j in y: 
          if i<0:
            fun.append(np.sin(i+j))
          else:
            fun.append(np.cos(i+j))
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5,6))
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(x,y,fun(x,y),10,cmap='inferno')
plt.show
```

And error msg:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py in _check_xyz(self, args, kwargs)
   1506 
   1507         if z.ndim != 2:
-> 1508             raise TypeError(f"Input z must be 2D, not {z.ndim}D")
   1509         if z.shape[0] < 2 or z.shape[1] < 2:
   1510             raise TypeError(f"Input z must be at least a (2, 2) shaped array, "
```

I really appreciate all the help :3

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: this code works correctly. You should show code which makes problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, first time here. As I said, I need to edit code by defining a function (def func[:,:]), but I dunno how make it works right in 3D plots.

Comment: you use the same name for `def fun(...)` and `fun = []` and this can make problems. you have to use different name ie, `data = []` - and at the end you have to use `return data`

Comment: and you use wrong names of arguments in `def fun(i, j)` - it assings parameters to `i, j` but you have to assign to `x, y` which you later need in `for ... in x:` - so you need `def fun(x, y)`

Comment: BTW: you forgot `()` in `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few mistakes.

1. you use the same name for `def fun()` and `fun = []` and sometimes it can make big problem
2. you use wrong names for arguments - you have `fun(i, j)` but later you use `for ... in x:`, `for ... in y:` so you need `fun(x, y)`
3. in first version you use two lists `z = []` and `zz = []` and you append `zz` in `z` - but in function you use only one list - and this can be the biggest problem with `0D`, `2D`, `3D`
4. you have to use `return ...` to send values from function to main code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# --- functions ---

def fun(x, y): 
    results = []  # z = []
    for i in x:
        row = []  # zz = []
        for j in y: 
            if i < 0:
                row.append(np.sin(i+j))
            else:
                row.append(np.cos(i+j))
        results.append(row)
    return results

# --- main ---

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 21)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 21)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(x, y, fun(x, y), 10, cmap='inferno')
plt.show()
```

---

**BTW:**

You could also put some spaces to make code more readable - ie. space after `,`, spaces around `=`, etc.

More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)